# scala akka futures in play framework with secure social

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0, future, securesocial

I'm using secure social and akka to send messages to a web client via a web socket using play frame work 2.3
Websocket

```
 def feedWS = WebSocket.tryAccept[JsValue] { implicit request =>
  SecureSocial.currentUser[PDUser].map { 
  maybeUser => maybeUser match {
    case Some(user) =>
      Right(Feed.start(user.id))
    case None => {
      Left(Redirect("/login"))
    }
  }
 }
```

But the map returns a future and Feed.start returns an future too. Something like
Object serving ws and connecting to an actor that pumps messages out (actor works fine)

```
def start(user: String): Future[(Iteratee[JsValue, _], Enumerator[JsValue])] = {
(actorFor(user) ? connect(user)).map {
  case ConnectedE(enumerator) => {
    val iteratee = Iteratee.foreach[JsValue] { event =>
      val things = FromJson.aList(event)
      actorFor(user) ! Subscribe(things)
    }.map { _ =>
      log.info("Disconnected")
      actorFor(user) ! UnSubscribe
    }
    (iteratee, enumerator)
  }
}
}
```

How do I compose them, if indeed I can or does it need an await?
At the moment I have a future of a future.

Comment: Can you not `flatMap` Future of Futures to get a single Future.

Comment: Yes after some reading that's what I did, and it worked fine.
Thanks anyway.